# How to Git diff two branches but showing an output similar to that of Git commit?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-diff, diffstat

If I do:

```
$ git checkout some_branch
[...]
$ git diff another_branch
```

It'll show a large diff between the branches.

Now there's a simplified, smaller<sup>1</sup> *diff* shown after applying a commit, or merge, I guess cherry picks too.

How can I show that smaller<sup>1</sup> *diff* when diffing two branches one branch from another branch?

<sub>1: Because format, **not** because contents.</sub>

Comment: What do you mean? If there is a large difference between two commits then why would you want a smaller diff? Can you show the commands you used for this smaller diff? And include the output as well?

Comment: I mean the smaller diff being shown when committing or merging. I'd need to trigger that from branches diffing.

Comment: That’d be a diff between the state in the current commit and its parent. That’s not a diff between two branches. Are you aware that a commit doesn’t contain a diff?

Comment: Branches diffing and parent-child diffing are cases of rev to rev diffing.

Comment: The diff between a parent and child is usually smaller because the difference between them is usually smaller. If the different between two branches is great then the difference is great. Unless I’m misunderstanding you...? Can you provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: Alright, I'll share a better example later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what I was looking for, at the manual page.

```
$ git diff --stat master
```

Will do what I need (having checked out the feature branch am diffing).